Ubuntu 24.04 not working on Dell G16 7630 with Nvidia drivers
My Dell G16 came with Windows and I immediately switched to Ubuntu.
I tried 24.04 as soon as it came out but I had issues with proprietary drivers (535) for the Nvidia 4060 Mobile on board. On Wayland I get a grey screen, on Xorg it stopped working after a few seconds and rebooting didn't help, it was completely frozen, not reaching even the login.
I installed 23.10 and it worked fine on Wayland with recommended proprietary driver 535.
I waited a month and then did the upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04, it started, but nvidia-smi was not responding, the "additional drivers" page was stuck on "custom driver installation" and I couldn't change anything. I tried forcing the drivers back to 535 but got the system frozen again.
Now I'm back to 23.10 (Proprietary drivers 535.171.04) which will end support soon.
Official Dell version for the G16 is 22.04, but they don't provide support for Linux
Hardware is the following

Dell G16 7630
I7 13650HX
32GB RAM
Intel Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics
(rev 04)
Nvidia AD107M (GeForce RTX 4060 Mobile) (rev a1)

Any suggestion? Rollback to recommended 22.04? Wait another month till end of 23.10 support?
I'm not a Linux expert.
Thanks

Does this answer your question? How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release? The upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 isn't recommended until the next point release sometime in August.

I'll try waiting for 24.04.1 for sure. Still thinking to revert back to 22.04.4 because it's a LTS. Thanks
